# String.format java method equivalent in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible in Dart to inject many variables values dynamically in a string like this ?

```
// Java code using String.format. In this case just 2 variables
String.format("Hello %s, You have %s years old", variable1, variable2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some alternatives. The most complete and sophisticated is using MessageFormat that is used for i18n.
https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/message_format/MessageFormat-class.html

And there is a dart pub package called "sprintf". It is similar to printf (in C) or String.format in Java.

Put sprintf in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  sprintf:
```

Dart example:

```
import 'package:sprintf/sprintf.dart';

void main() {
  double score = 8.8;
  int years = 25;
  String name = 'Cassio';

  String numbers = sprintf('Your score is %2.2f points.', [score]);
  String sentence = sprintf('Hello %s, You have %d years old.', [name, years]);

  print(numbers);
  print(sentence);
}
```

For simpler cases you could just use String interpolation:

```
  print('Hello $name, the sum of 4+4 is ${4 + 4}.');
```

results: Hello Cassio, the sum of 4+4 is:  8.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent in Dart is a string interpolation:

```dart
"Hello $variable1, you are $variable2 years old"
```

If you want to abstract over the variables, you can use a plain function:

```dart
String greet(String name, int age) =>
    "Hello $name, you are $age years old";
```

You can do the same for any *fixed* number of arguments.

If you want to pass a format string and a corresponding number of values, Dart does not have varargs. Instead you can create a function, like above, for the format string, and invoke it on a list of arguments using `Function.apply`:

```dart
String format(Function formatFunction, List<Object> values) => 
    Function.apply(formatFunction, values);

...
  format((a, b, c) => "The $a is $b in the $c!", ["dog", "lost", "woods"]);
  format((a, b) => "The $a is not $b!", ["status", "quo"]);
```

You lose static type safety, but you always did that with format strings too.

Comment: In this case, it's just 2 variables. What's about 3, 4, n variables ? With String.format method in Java, we can pass so many arguments.

Comment: Added something about that to the answer.

Comment: Sounds a cool approach ! I think there was a method in the dart framework which did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a class like:

```
class MyString {
  static format(String variable1, String variable2) {
    return "Hello $variable1, you are $variable2 years old";
  }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
MyString.format("Bob", "10"); // prints "Hello Bob, you are 10 years old"
```

Comment: why though? this is very much out of the context of the question

Comment: @iamyadunandan Just to provide another way of achieving.

Comment: In this case, it's just 2 variables. What's about 3, 4, n variables ? With String.format method in Java, we can pass so many arguments

Comment: @Agnaramon I understand, but there doesn't exist java's `Strings.format` equivalent in Dart.